# Init webSocket by alphanumeric message without quotation marks

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, socket.io

We are using nuxt-socket-io lib in the project and creating connection with init message '2probe' -> '3probe' Ex:

```
^ 2probe
v 3probe
^ 5
v 2
^ 3
v 2
...
```

I tried to do this in e2e tests using another lib 'rxjs', but it sends the message with quotation marks. Ex:

```
^ "2probe"
```

The BE doesn't send '3probe'

I there any possibility to send a 'init' message? I could be any lib, I need just a result

Comment: [DO NOT use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question.

Comment: @AmitMohanty I hope its ok now